# Strange output from Java Map keys

Tags: java, hash, dictionary, hashmap

I am trying to print my map to show both key and value for each print statement.  I have duplicate keys and duplicate values.  For example:

```
key -> value
house -> dog
house -> cat
dog -> house
dog -> cat
cat -> house
cat -> bike
```

This is my text file:

```
house   cat
house   dog
house   index
cat bike
cat house
cat index
dog house
dog cat
dog index
```

For some reason, my code is printing the string, "index" rather than the actual value.
My code is here:

```
//adding values from a text file of two words per line.
//those two words per line in the text file are tab delimitted

public static Map<String, String> animals = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader("animals.txt"));
String current_line;
String[] splitted_strings = new String[1];
while ((current_line = in.readLine()) != null){
   splitted_strings = current_line.split("\t");
   animals.put(splitted_strings[0], splitted_strings[1]);
}

//print statement
for(Map.Entry entry : animals.entrySet()) 
   System.out.println(entry.getValue() + " " + entry.getKey());
```

My output from simple print statements from my code shown below look like this:

```
index cat
index house
index dog
```

How can I add these values to a data structure to keep key pairs like above?
How can I get the output to be this?:

```
house cat
house dog
house index
cat bike
cat house
cat index
dog house
dog cat
dog index
```

Comment: It is not printing "index" instead of the key, it is printing "index" for the value.  Post the code you use to insert into the map.

Comment: This seems like a very good case for an [sscce](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: You will never get that output with a HashMap.  Keys are, by definition, unique.

Comment: @Aurand The program is printing value followed by key, so "index" is the value for every entry, and the printed keys are unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have duplicate keys and duplicate values.

No you don't. Not in a `Map<K,V>`. The keys are unique by definition.

If you *want* multiple values per key, you need something like [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/)'s [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html).

However, if the code you've presented is really printing "index" for every value, then I strongly suspect the map is incorrect to start with, and you've got a bug in your population code (which we can't see). (Either that, or you're using some custom class as the value and its `toString` method always returns "index".)

You should take a step back and look at your population code instead.

EDIT: I modified your sample code just enough so that it would compile, to come up with:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> animals = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("animals.txt")));
        String current_line;
        String[] splitted_strings = new String[1];
        while ((current_line = in.readLine()) != null){
            splitted_strings = current_line.split("\t");
            animals.put(splitted_strings[0], splitted_strings[1]);
        }
        for(Map.Entry entry : animals.entrySet()) 
            System.out.println(entry.getValue() + " " + entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

And with animals.txt of:

```
key1    value1
key2    value2
key3    value3
key4    value4
```

The output was:

```
value4 key4
value3 key3
value2 key2
value1 key1
```

No sign of "index" at all. So either that isn't your real population code (besides the compilation error), or your text file has "index" for every value...

Comment: Hi Jon, I've added the population code.  Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: @StephenD: And your file looks like...?

Comment: @StephenD: That population code doesn't even compile - there's no `InputStreamReader` constructor taking a `String` filename.

Comment: I really can't post my text file.  Its 4,726,878 lines of pairs.  In the file, there is at least 100 identical keys per word on the left, and at least 100 identical values per word on the right, which makes up the almost 5 million pairs.

Comment: @StephenD: Sure, you can't post the *real* file - but you could post a *test* file and the output you get with it, just like I've done. My guess is that you've got the value "index" as the last value in the file for each key, which would explain your output. But as I've explained, `Map` just doesn't *try* to store multiple values per key.

Comment: I have included a sample of my text file and output that I get.  I also added what I would like to see for output with an example of what I want to get.  Is this the wrong data structure for this type of problem?

Comment: HashMap is definitely the wrong data structure for a map with duplicate keys. However, you have more problems than that. I strongly recommend adding `System.out.println("Inserting key: "+splitted_strings[0]+" value: "+splitted_strings[1]);` immediately before or after your put call.

Comment: @StephenD: Your file shows *exactly* what I described: "My guess is that you've got the value "index" as the last value in the file for each key." Yes, as we've now said multiple times, `Map` is the wrong data structure for you. Look at `Multimap` in Guava, as linked in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using Guava, you can roll your own multimap based on `Map<String,Set<String>>`.

When adding a key-value pair, first check whether the key is already present. If not, put it with a Set containing only the new value. If the key is already present, get its Set and add the new value.

To check whether a pair exists, get the Set for the key and see if it contains the value.